# Wrap text around a tabular

Tags: tables, wrap

I would like to wrap some text around a `tabular` as the figure shows.

Do I have to use `minipage` and fix the width of the table, and the width of the text on the left hand?

Isn't there a simpler way?

[image]

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This is a MWE for David's answer (supplement).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig,lipsum,booktabs}
%------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
This is where the table goes with text wrapping around it. You may 
embed tabular environment inside wraptable environment and customize as you like.
%------------------------------------------
\begin{wraptable}{r}{5.5cm}
\caption{A wrapped table going nicely inside the text.}\label{wrap-tab:1}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}\\\toprule  
Header-1 & Header-1 & Header-1 \\\midrule
2 &3 & 5\\  \midrule
2 &3 & 5\\  \midrule
2 &3 & 5\\  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{wraptable} 
%------------------------------------------
{\lipsum[2] 
\par
Table~\ref{wrap-tab:1} is a wrapped table.
%------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a configuration for page-end? In my case when it's at the end of a page, it overflows the page margins instead of going into next page.

Comment: @fatih, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56176/143086)'s a similar (answered) question.

Comment: @Igor, thanks. that seems to be what I was looking for.

Answer (score 16):

The [`wrapfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) package provides this functionality.

Comment: Example please.

Answer (score 1):

Like in the example above, but use capital letters for R and L  to avoid huge amounts of white space with the table flowing into the margins

Change:
\begin{wraptable}{r}{5.5cm}

To

\begin{wraptable}{R}{5.5cm}

This issue is also discussed in this post: [Handling of wrapfig pictures in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56176/handling-of-wrapfig-pictures-in-latex/56177)

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this is using `\begin{wraptable}` to wrap around the table (outside `\tabular`)
.

```
\begin{wraptable}{r}{5.5cm}
\caption{A wrapped table going nicely inside the text.}\label{wrap-tab:1}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}\\\toprule  
Header-1 & Header-1 & Header-1 \\\midrule
2 &3 & 5\\  \midrule
2 &3 & 5\\  \midrule
2 &3 & 5\\  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{wraptable}
```