# Floating text around listing

Tags: floats, listings

I can't manage to let my text float around an listing. Assuming I have a text paragraph and I want the listing to be at the top right place with a certain width, and to be floated by the text.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{lstlisting} % this should be printed to the right of the text
public void Main (string[] args)
{
   // here goes some code
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

How can I do this?

**Solution according to Guido's answer:**

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[6]{r}{.6\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
\vspace{-2em}
\begin{lstlisting}
....
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

With three modifications:

- My listings produces captions with a box that is spanned over the whole textwidth, so I added a minipage.
- The listing was a bit to far below, so I added a vspace.
- The first optional parameter for `wrapfigure` specifies the number of lines the `wrapfigure` occupies (based on this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285203/198066)

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=textflow) for some pointers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, you can use the `wrapfig` package (see `textdoc wrapfig` for the documentation).

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{r}{.6\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting} 
public void Main (string[] args)
{
   // here goes some code
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{wrapfigure}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Producing
[image]

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thanks! Is there also a better approach for the second point in my modifications? (see edited post)

Comment: Yes, you can use the `aboveskip` option of `listings`, e.g., `\begin{listings}[aboveskip=-3pt]`

Comment: Is it possible to set the width of the `wrapfigure` automatically based on the max length of the code in the listing?