# I need this tikz and tabular sketch at the right of my presentation, and an itemize at left, but too much length

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, beamer, itemize, tabularx

I need this tikz and tabular sketch at the right of my presentation, and some text at left.

Unfortunatly the text is at left but in the down part of my frame, I need it at the center and starting from the top.

This is my code.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,draft]{beamer}



\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}

\frame[shrink]{\frametitle{Implementación del Metodo de diferencias en redes cristlinas}

\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[l]
\begin{tabular}{
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.45\textwidth}
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.45\textwidth}
  }
  \tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt] (imagen11)   
    {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{RepRedSC2D}};
  \caption{Red.Replicación de celdas Unitarias}
  \label{redes}
  & 
  \tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt] (imagen12)
    {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{11UnitSC2D}};
  \caption{Celda Unitaria SC-2D}
  \label{UnitSC2D}
  \\
  \tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt] (imagen21)
    {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{VecUSC2D}};
  \caption{Vecindade en el eje x para aproximar el metodo}
  \label{VecU}
  & 
  \tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt] (imagen22)
    {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{2UnitDivSC2D}};
  \caption{Division de la Celda Unidad}
  \label{Unit2Di}
 \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  remember picture,overlay,
  >=latex,
  shorten >= 10pt,
  shorten <= 10pt,
  magenta
]
\draw[->]
  (imagen11) -- (imagen12);
\draw[->,shorten <= 30pt]
  (imagen12) -- (imagen22);
\draw[->]
  (imagen22) -- (imagen21);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{4\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Here are the expresion of neighbors of $U_{a}$
\item We have here the the function $\psi$
\item We have here the the function $\psi$
\item We have here the the function $\psi$
\item We have here the the function $\psi$
\item We have here the the function $\psi$
\item We have here the the function $\psi$
\item We have here the the function $\psi$
\end{itemize}

\end{minipage}

}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of controling `height` of the image, change the `width`.

Comment: Did you try with `beamer` `columns` environment? Or with optional `[pos]` parameter for `minipage`?

Comment: Try using the [wrapfig](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) environment. For some examples see this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56176/handling-of-wrapfig-pictures-in-latex

Comment: I get the text on the right, centred vertically and the tabular/images on the left. (Obviously I had to substitute another image for it to compile at all.) Asking for a `minipage` 4 times `\textwidth` is not really sensible, by the way ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you like to obtain something like this?
[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,draft]{beamer}
    \usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
    \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[shrink]
 \frametitle{Implementación del Metodo de diferencias en redes cristlinas}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Here are the expresion of neighbors of $U_{a}$
\item We have here the function $\psi$
\item We have here the function $\psi$
\item We have here the function $\psi$
\item We have here the function $\psi$
\item We have here the function $\psi$
\item We have here the function $\psi$
\item We have here the function $\psi$
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[l]
\begin{tabular}{
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.5\hsize}
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.5\hsize}
  }
  \tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt] (imagen11)
    {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}};
  \caption{Red.Replicación de celdas Unitarias}
  \label{redes}
  &
  \tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt] (imagen12)
    {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}};
  \caption{Celda Unitaria SC-2D}
  \label{UnitSC2D}
  \\
  \tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt] (imagen21)
    {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}};
  \caption{Vecindade en el eje x para aproximar el metodo}
  \label{VecU}
  &
  \tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt] (imagen22)
    {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}};
  \caption{Division de la Celda Unidad}
  \label{Unit2Di}
 \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  remember picture,overlay,
  >=latex,
  shorten >= 10pt,
  shorten <= 10pt,
  magenta
]
\draw[->]
  (imagen11) -- (imagen12);
\draw[->,shorten <= 30pt]
  (imagen12) -- (imagen22);
\draw[->]
  (imagen22) -- (imagen21);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you use frame as an environment? Makes the code easier to read.

Comment: @daleif, I just copied OP code. ... I will correct my solution.