# `wrapfigure` puts too much vertical space around the figure

Tags: wrapfigure

I am trying to put a figure in my document using `wrapfig` but it shifts the text below it too much.

I insert my image like this:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.25\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.25\columnwidth]{Images/Domains.pdf}
\caption{Birds}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

and what I get is this:

[image]

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56176/handling-of-wrapfig-pictures-in-latex) doesn't seem to help and I would not want to manually calibrate some negative `\vspace` every time I insert a figure. My questions are:

- Can I have `wrapfig` insert zero space above and below the image?
- I have had to specify the same width twice in my main code: is there any way I could specify that only once?

Comment: Please provide complete small document, by which we can reproduce your problem. YAre you avare, that `wrapfigure` works (well) only at paragraph with text?

Comment: For your second question, you can use `\linewidth` *inside* the wrapfigure environment.

Comment: One of the optional arguments is tne number of lines.  Note that images and equations count as one line, so the number may need to be very small.  If that doesn't work, use paracol.

Comment: @Leonardo, there could be a lot of things giving the effect you show. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that people here can help.