# Make a wrapfigure not overflow a page

Tags: wrapfigure

I have a `wrapfigure`, and as shown on the image below, the image and the caption go outside of the page and overlap the space where the page number is. Is there a way to fix it?

[image: image overflowing the page and going near the page number]

Minimal reproducible example (with lipsum text and blank image)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian,ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.3cm,bottom=2cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,marginparwidth=0.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig, float}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\begin{document}

\lipsum[150]\lipsum[150]\lipsum[150]\lipsum[150]\lipsum[150]\lipsum[150]\lipsum[150]\lipsum[150]

\subsection{subsection}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0pt}
    \centering
    \rule{8cm}{8cm} 
    \caption{image}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[150]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: hard to say as you provided no example but `\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0pt}` with `L` not `l` allows the figure to move at a page break. Or simply move it in the source

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos added example

Comment: thanks for the example, `L` works here (image goes to next page)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks, although, is it somehow possible to resize the image to fit the remaining space?

Comment: not automatically (would you want it to shrink to  just one line high with no warning?) You can of course  use `height=...` on `\includegraphics` to fix any partcular case,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok, thanks!

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669240/latex-wrapfigure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is usually best to move `wrapfig` by hand in the source so it ends up in a "good" position, however it does support moving at a page break to avoid this problem if you use uppercase position. So `{L}` here not `{l}`. The image goes to the next page in this example.

[image]

Alternatively you can adjust the size and position here just by eye, stealing as much space above and below as possible.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian,ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.3cm,bottom=2cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,marginparwidth=0.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig, float}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\begin{document}

\lipsum[150]\lipsum[150]\lipsum[150]\lipsum[150]\lipsum[150]\lipsum[150]\lipsum[150]\lipsum[150]

\subsection{subsection}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0pt}
    \centering
    \raisebox{-1.2cm}[3cm]{\rule{8cm}{5cm}}
    \caption{image}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[150]

\end{document}
```