# How to put figure on the one of the corners of the pages in LaTeX?

Tags: alignment, wrapfigure

I always think that it is better to put figures on the one of the four cornors of the page. As in the [site](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1029/2022WR032716), the journal of **Water Resource Research** always do this.

For example 1:

[image: On the upper left corner]

For example 2:

[image: on the bottom left corner]

I checked the LaTeX template of the **Water Resource Research** on the [site](https://www.agu.org/-/media/Files/Publications/Latex_submission_guidelines_Jan162023.pdf?la=en&hash=182A5546F9DD218666E7FDE3B75B966F), but it didn't contain any code about this function.

Is there a package to do that? Thanks.

Comment: I actually address this in my second solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669240/latex-wrapfigure

Comment: You can manually insert wrapfig (or paracol) in the middle of a paragraph in order to  hit the corners.  You have to w;ait until everything else is done.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks for your kind reply.  I saw your answer, it basically satisfies my vision for picture placement. but it can't extend the figure in to the blank on left or right blank of the page. And why didn't you make a package to **CTAN**?

Comment: What, and have to support it?!  It would help to know what the deal is with the left margin.  LaTeX normally makes the text area the same as the header width.  You would have to use paracol or flowfram to achive the form shown above.