# I'm trying to insert a image inside an itemize. But i want some text on the side of the image

Tags: graphics, itemize, text

The code section is:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item....
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{Pic/Ciclo cardiaco.png}
\end{minipage}
\item.....
\end{itemize}
```

I need text on the side.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Please extend your code so that it is compilable, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` so that a potential helper doesn't ave to do any guessing.

Comment: This looks like a job for wrapfig.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669240/latex-wrapfigure/669294?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C16.9111#669294 to put the figure at the top of the column.

Comment: you don't need minipage `\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{Pic/Ciclo cardiaco.png}hello`  would put text next to an image

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `tikz` to place the side text.

*(You don't need to understand tikz code)*

The command `\InsertImageText{<image name>}{<side text>}` places the image and text on its right side.

You can set the width of the image and the width of the text, its font, and its x-y position relative to the center of the right side of the image.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % ONLY for dummy text   

%**************************************** added 
\usepackage{tikz}
\newlength{\imageheight}
\newlength{\imagewidth}
\newlength{\TextWidth}
\newlength{\TextXshift}
\newlength{\TextYshift}
% define the parameters  here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\setlength{\imagewidth}{0.7\textwidth} % set the image width
\newcommand{\TextFont}{\sffamily\small}% set the side text font
\setlength{\TextWidth}{0.2\textwidth}% set the width of the side text
\setlength{\TextXshift}{2ex}% horizontal shift of the side text
\setlength{\TextYshift}{0pt}% vertical shift of the side text

\newcommand{\InsertImageText}[2]{% \InsertImageText{<image name>}{<side text>}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (A)[inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=2ex] {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{#1}};
        \node[%
        font=\TextFont,
        align =flush left,
        text width=\TextWidth,
        right= \TextXshift, 
        yshift =-\TextYshift,
        inner sep= 0pt] at (A.east) {#2};
    \end{tikzpicture}   
}
%****************************************

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Fase B--C} -- \kant[1]
    
    \InsertImageText{example-image}{As we have already seen, what we have alone been able   to show is that the objects in space and time would be falsified.}
    
    \item \textbf{Fase C--D} -- \kant[2]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

**OPTION**

An equivalent result can be achieved using a tabular environment, in this example using the `nicematrix` package and its convenient `\Block` command to insert vertically centered content into the tabular cell.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % ONLY for dummy text   

%**************************************** added 
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newlength{\imageheight}
\newlength{\imagewidth}
\newlength{\TextWidth}
\newlength{\TextXshift}
\newlength{\TextYshift}
% define the parameters  here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\setlength{\imagewidth}{0.7\textwidth} % set the image width
\newcommand{\TextFont}{\sffamily\small}% set the side text font
\setlength{\TextWidth}{0.2\textwidth}% set the width of the side text
\setlength{\TextXshift}{2ex}% horizontal shift of the side text

\newcommand{\InsertImageText}[2]{% \InsertImageText{<image name>}{<side text>}
\vspace*{2ex}\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{l@{\hspace{\TextXshift}}Wc{\TextWidth}}
    \Block{1-1}{\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{#1}} & \Block[l]{1-1}{\TextFont #2}\\
\end{NiceTabular}
}
%****************************************

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Fase B--C} -- \kant[1]
    
    \InsertImageText{example-image}{As we have already seen, what we have alone been able   to show is that the objects in space and time would be falsified.}
    
    \item \textbf{Fase C--D} -- \kant[2]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```