# How can I put the wrapfigure picture in the top of the page and not in the beginning of the paragraph

Tags: floats, wrapfigure, wrap, wrapfig

How can I put the image in the top of the page in between the paragraph?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-6]

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.25\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{x.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669240/latex-wrapfigure, particularly the solution using `\parshape`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To illustrate my comment:

You might want to move the definitions to another file and `\input`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only
\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\wp@image}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{wrappage}{O{0} m O{0} m}{\par
% #1 (optional) is the number of lines until the end of the page
% #2 is r (right) or l (left)
% #3 (optional) is the number of lines for the image.
% #4 width (or 0pt to compute).
  \xdef\wp@page{#1}%
  \ifnum\wp@page=0\relax
    \dimen0=\dimexpr \pagegoal-\pagetotal-0.5\baselineskip\relax
    \xdef\wp@page{\the\numexpr \dimen0/\baselineskip}%
  \fi
  \xdef\wp@side{#2}%
  \xdef\wp@lines{#3}%
  \xdef\wp@width{#4}%
  \def\@captype{figure}%
  \wp@environ}% body here
{\endwp@environ
  \ifnum\wp@lines=0\relax
    \dimen0=\dimexpr \ht\wp@image+\dp\wp@image+\intextsep\relax
    \xdef\wp@lines{\the\numexpr \dimen0/\baselineskip}%
  \fi
  \ifdim \wp@page\baselineskip>\dimexpr\wp@lines\baselineskip+\intextsep\relax% put figure on this page
    \AddToHookNext{para/before}{\begin{wrapfigure}[\wp@lines]{\wp@side}{\wp@width}
      \box\wp@image
    \end{wrapfigure}}
  \else
    \if r\wp@side\relax
      \wp@right% put image on right side
    \else
      \if l\wp@side\relax
        \wp@left% put image on left side
      \else
        \errmessage{Bad wrappage argument: \textbf{\wp@side} must be \texbf{r} or \textbf{l}.}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
    
\def\wp@right{% handle right side wrapfig
  \afterpage{\xdef\wp@extra{\the\dimexpr \wp@lines\baselineskip-\ht\AP@partial-\dp\AP@partial}%
    \noindent\hspace{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wp@width}%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox-\height}[\ht\strutbox][0pt]{\box\wp@image}%
    \vskip-\baselineskip
    \unvbox\AP@partial
    \ifdim\wp@extra>0pt\relax
      \AddToHookNext{para/begin}{\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{\wp@width}
        \vskip-\intextsep
        \rule{0pt}{\wp@extra}
        \vskip-\intextsep
      \end{wrapfigure}\vskip-\baselineskip\indent}%
    \fi}
  \xdef\wp@parshape{\the\numexpr \wp@page+\wp@lines+1}%
  \edef\wp@test{\the\textwidth}%
  \count1=\wp@page\relax
  \loop\ifnum\count1>0
    \advance\count1 by -1
    \xdef\wp@parshape{\wp@parshape\space 0pt \wp@test}%
  \repeat
  \edef\wp@test{\the\dimexpr \textwidth-\wp@width-\columnsep}%
  \count1=\wp@lines\relax
  \loop\ifnum\count1>0
    \advance\count1 by -1
    \xdef\wp@parshape{\wp@parshape\space 0pt \wp@test}%
  \repeat
  \xdef\wp@parshape{\wp@parshape\space 0pt \the\textwidth}%
  \AddToHookNext{para/before}{\parshape=\wp@parshape}%
}

\def\wp@left{% handle left side wrapfig
  \afterpage{\xdef\wp@extra{\the\dimexpr \wp@lines\baselineskip-\ht\AP@partial-\dp\AP@partial}%
    \noindent\raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\box\wp@image}%
    \vskip-\baselineskip
    \unvbox\AP@partial
    \ifdim\wp@extra>0pt\relax
      \AddToHookNext{para/begin}{\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{\wp@width}
        \vskip-\intextsep
        \rule{0pt}{\wp@extra}
        \vskip-\intextsep
      \end{wrapfigure}\vskip-\baselineskip\indent}%
    \fi}
  \xdef\wp@parshape{\the\numexpr \wp@page+\wp@lines+1}%
  \edef\wp@test{\the\textwidth}%
  \count1=\wp@page\relax
  \loop\ifnum\count1>0
    \advance\count1 by -1
    \xdef\wp@parshape{\wp@parshape\space 0pt \wp@test}%
  \repeat
  \edef\wp@temp{\the\dimexpr \wp@width+\columnsep}%
  \edef\wp@test{\the\dimexpr \textwidth-\wp@temp}%
  \count1=\wp@lines\relax
  \loop\ifnum\count1>0
    \advance\count1 by -1
    \xdef\wp@parshape{\wp@parshape\space \wp@temp \wp@test}%
  \repeat
  \xdef\wp@parshape{\wp@parshape\space 0pt \the\textwidth}%
  \AddToHookNext{para/before}{\parshape=\wp@parshape}\par
}

\NewEnviron{wp@environ}{% put \BODY into \wp@image
  \ifdim\wp@width=0pt
    \savebox\wp@image{\varwidth{\textwidth}
      \renewcommand{\caption}[2][\empty]{\par}% dummy caption
      \BODY
    \endvarwidth}%
    \xdef\wp@width{\the\wd\wp@image}%
  \fi
  \global\setbox\wp@image=\hbox{\parbox{\wp@width}{\BODY}}%
}
\makeatother
  
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{wrappage}{l}{0.25\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{x.jpg}
\end{wrappage}

\lipsum[6-7]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give wrapfig some help; insert the figure at the page break.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]


% {6}
Suspendisse vel felis. Ut lorem lorem, interdum eu, tincidunt sit amet,{\parfillskip=0pt\par}

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.25\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,height=8cm]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}
\noindent
laoreet vitae, arcu. Aenean faucibus pede eu ante. Praesent enim elit,
rutrum at, molestie non, nonummy vel, nisl. Ut lectus eros, malesuada
sit amet, fermentum eu, sodales cursus, magna. Donec eu purus. Quisque
vehicula, urna sed ultricies auctor, pede lorem egestas dui, et
convallis elit erat sed nulla. Donec luctus. Curabitur et nunc. Aliquam
dolor odio, commodo pretium, ultricies non, pharetra in, velit. Integer
arcu est, nonummy in, fermentum faucibus, egestas vel, odio.


\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```