# Latex wrapfigure page break if the figure does not fit to the page

Tags: floats, wrapfigure

I have founded a solution on this page: [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/515781/287023)

If the figure does not fit it is allowing a page breake, that is working.

But the one extra line appears after the figure, and I do not know why, and I do not know how to solve thi issue.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parskip}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{wrapfigure}{\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}}

\newsavebox\curwrapfig
\makeatletter
\long\def\wrapfiguresafe#1#2#3{
  \sbox\curwrapfig{#3}
  \par\penalty-100
  \begingroup
    \dimen@\pagegoal \advance\dimen@-\pagetotal
    \advance\dimen@-\baselineskip
    \ifdim \ht\curwrapfig>\dimen@
      \break%
    \fi%
  \endgroup%
  \begin{wrapfigure}{#1}{#2}
    \usebox\curwrapfig
  \end{wrapfigure}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\wrapfiguresafe{r}{0mm}{\centering\rule{3cm}{6cm}}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Which one extra line do you mean? I don't see any line. Or do you mean that you think that there is one short line too much?

Comment: @Skillmon I have just updated my screenshot.

Comment: If you add `\vfill\hrule` to the bottom of the page, you will see that the wrapfigure will overlap the last shortened line of text (text can shrink or expand slightly to fit)

Answer (score 1):

The `wrapfigure` environment has two optional parameters that your wrapping macro don't support, also the support for `wrapfigure`'s second mandatory argument of your macro was incorrect as well. The following is an altered implementation that should correctly implement a wrapper that supports both optional argument and should behave correct with the second mandatory argument not being equal to `0pt`.

The first optional argument of `wrapfigure` specifies how many short lines the figure should produce. The following sets that parameter to 14 which is correct in your example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parskip}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{wrapfigure}{\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \ForwardOarg #1#2
  {
    \tl_if_eq:nnTF {#1} {#2}
      { \tl_clear:N \ProcessedArgument }
      { \tl_set:Nn \ProcessedArgument {[{#2}]} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newsavebox\curwrapfig
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\wrapfiguresafe
  {>{\ForwardOarg{}}O{} m >{\ForwardOarg{}}O{} m m}
  {%
    \ifdim#4=\z@
      \sbox\curwrapfig{#5}%
    \else
    \sbox\curwrapfig{\parbox[b]{#4}{#5}}%
    \fi
    \par\penalty-100
    \begingroup
      \dimen@\pagegoal \advance\dimen@-\pagetotal
      \advance\dimen@-\baselineskip
      \ifdim \ht\curwrapfig>\dimen@
        \break
      \fi
    \endgroup
    \begin{wrapfigure}#1{#2}#3{#4}%
      \usebox\curwrapfig
    \end{wrapfigure}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\wrapfiguresafe[14]{r}{0mm}{\centering\rule{3cm}{6cm}}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see, is it mandatory to count down the number of line (in this case 14), or is there another way to make it fully automatic (without manual line counting)?

Comment: @mala97 the fully automatic approach was the one that got the count wrong...